# twitter login swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, twitter

I want to implement twitter login in my app but i get error.

```
Class TWTRAppAuthProvider is implemented in both /Users/mohamedeldewaik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F7EFA9B-EB86-4E18-8386-284E21A73F92/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/37DD8EB8-2854-44CB-ABAD-3FDADA0FCD1E/alharamin pass.app/Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit (0x105296548) and /Users/mohamedeldewaik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F7EFA9B-EB86-4E18-8386-284E21A73F92/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/37DD8EB8-2854-44CB-ABAD-3FDADA0FCD1E/alharamin pass.app/Frameworks/TwitterCore.framework/TwitterCore (0x10510e370). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

**I tried this below code but it crashes**

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                print("signed in as \(session?.userName)");
            } else {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
            }
        })
```

This is my app delegate

```
import TwitterKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"XzbZgtanfchiPGRRpII1gu70Z",consumerSecret: "4cNlyYssitGQjoWob4eGnBYeCVP20yVNL9P7w9fI4TzhO4RGKg")

    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {
        return true
    }

    return true
  }
}
```

so how can i implement twitter without this error i searched more and more for a solution but i don't get a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you added a callback Url in the dashboard like below

```
twitterkit-CONSUMERKEY://
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a Callback url in your twitter dashboard as below (`twitterkit-CONSUMERKEY://`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Login

```
buttonLogin = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: { session, error in
            if (session != nil) {
                print("signed in as \(session!.userName)");
            } else {
                print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
            }
        })
```